# Tkinter: How to deiconify a popup window (and give it focus)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and struggling with making `iconify()` and `deiconify()` work for a popup window. Currently the popup window will not `deiconify()` after having been iconified. Here is a minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class PopupWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    """ Show summary
    """
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(master=root)
        self.root = root
        self.geometry("600x400")
        self.title("Summary")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_window)
        button = tk.Button(
            self, text="Close", command=self.close_window)
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.focus_force()
        self.grab_set()

    def close_window(self):
        self.iconify()
        #self.withdraw()
        #self.transient()
        #self.root.grab_set()
        #self.root.focus_force()

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    """ The main window
    """
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.popup_window = None
        self.configure_window()

    def open_popup_window(self):
        """ Opens the popup window
        """
        if self.popup_window is None:
            self.popup_window = PopupWindow(self)
        else:
            self.popup_window.deiconify()
            #self.popup_window.lift()
            self.popup_window.focus_force()
            #self.popup_window.grab_set()

    def configure_window(self):
        """ Configure the main window
        """
        self.geometry("600x400")
        self.title("Cinema bookkeeper")
        self.bind_all('<Control-w>', lambda e: self.destroy())
        button = tk.Button(
            self, text="Open popup window", command=self.open_popup_window)
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)


def main():
    window = MainWindow()
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

When I click the "Open popup window" button a second time after it first has been iconified, nothing happens. Expected behavior was that the popup window would reappear and get focus. I can make it work if I use `grab_set()` but I would like not make the popup window modal such that both windows still can receive input at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grab_set` method routes all the events of the application to the specified widget.

Since you have called `self.grab_set()` on the popup window, the main window will refuse to take any event (the button is never clicked to begin with) and so the program doesn't work.

Removing that would make it work.

Comment: Thanks that seems to help, another thing is that `self.iconify()` (or clicking the minimize button of the window) does not work as expected on Ubuntu. It is not possible to make the window reappear by calling `deiconify()` in this case. Instead, if I use `self.withdraw()`, then I can make the window reappear by calling `deiconify()`

Comment: @HåkonHægland I am not really sure about the reason of that behaviour as of now, probably that makes up a new question altogether.